# How do I set and get a Vector<Integer> in two different classes?

Tags: java, vector, getter-setter

I need to set and get a Vector in two different classes but I seem to be losing the size of the Vector in the process. If I do v.size() I get 100 for example. Then I use a setter. Then in another class I use a getter to access this Vector again. If I do v.size() in this new class I get 0. The below code is a rough example of what I have, as I can't copy paste my code exactly, since it's part of a larger private project.

```
public class Params {
    private Vector<Integer> _v = new Vector<Integer>();
    public Vector<Integer> get_v(){return _v;}
    public void set_v(Vector<Integer> _v){this._v = _v;}
}

public class a {
    v.add(10);
    System.out.println(v.size()); //returns 1
    Params p = new Params();
    p.set_v(v);
}

public class b {
    Params p = new Params();
    v = p.get_v();
    System.out.println(v.size()); //Returns 0
}
```

Comment: You have two different instances of `Params`...

Comment: before p.get_v(); you are creating new Params(); = new Vector = 0 size

Comment: Don't use `Vector`. It's crap and it's more-or-less effectively deprecated. Use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: Yeah class a and class b are in two totally different files. I need to reintroduce Params in both files to access the getters and setters inside.

Comment: Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector

Comment: @matoni *Even if* a thread-safe implementation is needed, [it's not recommended to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

When you make `Params = new Params()` on `b` you create a new object of the class `Params`, and this new object initializes a new empty Vector on the `_v` property.

You should pass the object created on `a` to `b` so this class can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are re initializing your Params class. In essence, you are creating two Params Objects and both have their own Vector, they are completely separate. You could solve this by making your vector `static` thus making the different instances have the same vector.

Answer (score 0):

You create two difference instances of `Params`. Each of them has a different variable named `_v`.

To solve this problem You need to use only a single copy of `Params` or define `_v` as `static`.

---

**Some tips not directly related to the question**

Don't use `Vector`. The use of `Vector` is deprecated.

If you are not in a multithreading environment use an `ArrayList`, if you are in a multithreading environment use a synchronized `List` created with the [`synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) method of `Collections` class.

Name your classes in uppercase.

Give readable names to your classes and variables.

Comment: The real problem is that he should be using an IDE that warns him that Vector is deprecated. Otherwise yes he should probably follow what his IDE says...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for all the help! Wow I've never used this before and I was very pleased with the results. So I solved my problem, I basically just defined my Params once and pass it on to each class instead of recreating it.